# Why is "treated" in the past tense in "it's time we treated our teachers with the same level of respect..."?

Tags: tense, subjunctives

Barack Obama told a Virginia school last year, "I think it's time we **treated** our teachers with the same level of respect right here in the United States of America."

I totally understand what he's saying, but I want to ask how that 'treated' is grammatically possible? Cause he's saying 'It's time we~', which means he's talking about what we should do in the future (?), but why did he say that past verb?

Comment: That's the idiom: "It's time we VERBed". Because English.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61963/why-do-we-say-its-time-we-ate-and-not-its-time-we-eat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/it-s-time) we can use the expression **it’s time** either + subject + past verb form to refer to the present moment:

> I think it's time we treated our teachers with the same level of respect right here in the United States of America.

or with a verb in the to-infinitive:

> I think it's time to treat our teachers with the same level of respect right here in the United States of America.

Answer (score -1):

It's the past subjunctive of the verb "to treat".  You could use the present subjunctive in that situation as well, but never the present indicative or past indicative.